# Stanford NLP Lexparser loadModel()

Tags: c#, stanford-nlp, java-io, objectinputstream

I'm currently using the below C# code to create my Lexparser with success:

```
return LexicalizedParser.loadModel(projectDir + @"StanfordResources/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz");
```

But due to deployment reasons I would rather embed the 'englishPCFG.ser.gz' file as some sort of resource either into the assembly or as a Resource.resx.

So I try to read my byte[] file as so:

```
ObjectInputStream stream = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(Resource.englishPCFG_ser));
        return LexicalizedParser.loadModel(stream);
```

But I get the below error:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 1F8B0800
```

Is there another way to load this rather than from a file path or am I doing a silly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1F8B0800` is the GZIP header, which makes sense, given the name of the file you're trying to read. So you need to put `java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream` between the `ByteArrayInputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`:

```
new ObjectInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(Resource.englishPCFG_ser)))
```